# NebulaGraph Database: how to filter out the path corresponding to a certain rank value

Tags: nebula-graph

The details are as follows:

- NebulaGraph version is 2.5.0.
- Deployment method is stand-alone.

I don't know how to write the grammar because I didn’t find relevant cases in the manual.
I only want to return the path whose rank value of follow is 1

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. See [ask] for further guidance on asking questions. Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the edge `[e:follow*1]` with `[e:follow]`. At present, nebula internally regards the `*` after the edge as variable length even if it is written as `1`. For the variable length edge, the type of the variable `e` becomes a list, so `rank(e) == 1` here always returns `false`;

Try again with the following query:

```
MATCH p=(v)-[e:follow]-(v2)
WHERE id(v) == "player10" and rank(e) == 1
RETURN p
LIMIT 100
```